# Problems with pairing using maps and lists for a lending system

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my lending system to function correctly, the problem seems to be focused in the part of the code below.

I'm trying to make it so every time I enter an item ID and borrower ID it finds the inputted ID's (if correct), pairs and retrieves them from the accessors to initiate a transaction. Every time I input an item and ID I always get the "No user input found" error I made, I suspect its because i'm doing something wrong with the LoanTransaction part of my code as I know the item ID and borrower ID I input to test is correct.

I'm still quite new to using maps and lists together so any advice and help would be useful stuff for me. Many thanks!

## Suspect code

```
LoanTransaction mrkr = null
for (LoanTransaction t: parent.getLoans()) {
  if (t.getBorrower() == bwr && t.getItem() == itm) {
    mrkr = t;
    break;
  }
}
```

## Full Method

```
public void loanTransaction() {
    Integer itmID = new Integer(txtItemID.getText());
    Item itm = parent.getItems().get(itmID);
    Integer borrowerID = new Integer(txtBorrowerID.getText());
    Borrower bwr = parent.getBorrowers().get(borrowerID);

    if (itm == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Item not found",
          "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }
    Borrower bby = itm.getBorrowedBy();
    if (bby != null) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Already on loan",
          "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }

   LoanTransaction mrkr = null;
    for (LoanTransaction t: parent.getLoans()) {
      if (t.getBorrower() == bwr && t.getItem() == itm) {
        mrkr = t;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (mrkr == null) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No user input found",
          "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }
        parent.getLoans().add(mrkr);
        itm.clearBorrowedBy();
        itm.setBorrowedBy(bwr);
        System.out.printf("Item loaned: [%s]\n\n", itm);
}
```

## Accessors

```
public Map<Integer, Borrower>  getBorrowers() { return borrowers; }
public Map<Integer, Item>      getItems()     { return items; }
public List<LoanTransaction> getLoans()       { return loans; }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a == comparison in Java between two objects, it’s an identity comparison, not an equals comparison. I don’t know how you judge if two borrowers are the same, but this code would only work if the two borrower objects were literally the same instance. What you want to do is use the equals method:

t.getBorrower().equals(bwr)

And similarly for the Item class. Also, you want to make sure you implement the equals (and hashCode) methods in your Borrower and Item classes such that each object knows how to judge itself equal to another object of the same type (such as comparing borrower IDs). If you don’t, it’ll still be an identity comparison.

Comment: I tried that and I still keep hitting the "No user input error".

Comment: Is the bwr variable null?

Comment: I dont believe so.                                                     
Borrower bwr = parent.getBorrowers().get(borrowerID);

Comment: If there is no borrower object in that map for that borrower ID, the get will return null. You should check.

Comment: I do have borrowers though, in a separate class I can list borrowers with this code (see below) and it does list them correctly so I have no idea why my code in the class im working on cant seem to match the ID's.    
   ------public void listBorrowers() {
    System.out.println("Borrowers:");
    for (Borrower b: borrowers.values()) {
      System.out.println(b);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

Comment: You check itm for a null value. Check bwr right after that block.

Comment: Ok made a block right after itm to check for null value, passes through without telling me bwr is null so I assume it must be holding a value im inputting